# Making all class properties observable in a dart PolymerElement template

Tags: dart

In the following example, when the Update Class button is clicked, {{testClass.someProperty}} is updated with the new class' someProperty, but updating testClass.someProperty does not update {{testClass.someProperty}} in the template.

I thought making the TestClass @observable would make its properties observable and when updating the property, the property in the template would change.

What would be the correct way to bind TestElement.testClass.someProperty to {{testClass.someProperty}}, and as an extension, any class' properties to a Polymer Element template?

**test_class.dart**

```dart
library test;

import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";

@observable
class TestClass extends ObservableBase {
  String someProperty;
  TestClass(this.someProperty);
}
```

**test_element.dart:**

```dart
library test_element;

import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";
import "test_class.dart";

@CustomTag("test-element")
class TestElement extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  @observable
  TestClass testClass = new TestClass("original");

  void updateClass() {
    testClass = new TestClass("xyz");
  }
  void updateProperty() {
    testClass.someProperty = "foobar";
  }
}
```

**test_element.html**

```dart
<polymer-element name="test-element">
  <template>
    {{testClass.someProperty}}
    <button on-click="updateProperty">Update Property</button>
    <button on-click="updateClass">Update Class</button>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="test_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**test.dart**

```dart
library test;

int main() {

}
```

**test.html:**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="import" href="test_element.html" />
    <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <test-element></test-element>
    <script type="application/dart" src="test.dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by moving @observable from the class to the property. I thought annotating the class with @observable was supposed to be the same as annotating all the properties as observable, but that didn't work:

**test.dart**

library test;

```
import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";

class TestClass extends ObservableBase {
  @observable
  String someProperty;
  TestClass(this.someProperty);
}
```

Comment: I encountered the same issue. It seems to work without extending ObservableBase (just add @observable annotation on attributes).
Did you fill a bug ?

Comment: I actually haven't been able to get this to work at all recently but I haven't spent much time on it. I didn't file a bug because I wasn't entirely clear on how it is supposed to work and tbh I don't understand the difference between `@observable` and `@published`. I'll try and spend some time on it later today probably submit something to the misc mail list to make sure I understand it.

Comment: Yes I found that too.  Bit it doesn't work for getter-s except for the first try (e.g. constructor). I don't consider the observer to be reliable at this point.